# iOS keyboard dismissal with multiple UIGestureRecognizers

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

In my main app view which contains both a `UITextField` and a `UITableView`, I have the "usual" code using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to dismiss the virtual keyboard if a tap is detected outside of the keyboard while I'm editing the contents of the `UITextField`.

An added feature is that this is only enabled if the virtual keyboard is actually shown - I don't want "background taps" to cause editing to end if the virtual keyboard isn't visible, but nor do I want background taps to trigger their normal behaviour - they should be consumed if the virtual keyboard is currently showing.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...

    tapper = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped))

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardShown), name:
        NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UIKeyboardDidShowNotification"), object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardHidden), name:
        NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UIKeyboardDidHideNotification"), object: nil)
}

@IBAction func keyboardShown(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapper!)
}

@IBAction func keyboardHidden(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    view.removeGestureRecognizer(tapper!)
}

@IBAction func viewTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    view.endEditing(false)
}
```

This *mostly* works, except that the `UITableView` has interactive header cells which each *also* have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` attached.

The net result is that if I click on a header cell the gesture recognizer on that cell gets fired, and not the one on the parent view, and the keyboard doesn't get dismissed.  If I click on the data cells instead, everything works fine.

If it matters, my `UITableView` has its own `UIViewController` subclass and is contained in a nested `UIView` - the table is too complicated to have that code in my main view controller.

How can I prevent the sub-view's gesture recognizers from handling these taps when the parent view's recognizer is attached so that the parent view can handle them instead?

Comment: Is it too blunt an instrument to suggest that your view controller use a custom view class as its root, which overrides `hitTest:withEvent:` to do the "has the user touched the screen?" test, rather than use a gesture recogniser? That would allow passive listening — you don't need to consume the touch, you can pass it along as usual, but also know that there's a touch entering the system.

Comment: @Tommy I left out an important detail (now included) - I would need to (conditionally) consume these touches because I don't want the normal touch events to be triggered when anything other than the text field is touched - I just want the keyboard to disappear.

Comment: @Tommy thanks for the hint, I've now got a better working solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented what I consider a "temporary" solution by also observing the virtual keyboard notifications in the `UITableView's` controller, tracking the keyboard visibility state, and then implementing this `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method on the header cells' gesture recognizer:

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return !keyboardShowing
}
```

This duplicates a certain amount of functionality from the main view in the sub-view which really shouldn't need to know about the state of the keyboard.  I'm still looking for a method that can be handled entirely from within the parent view.

---

**EDIT** - with thanks to @Tommy for the hint, I now have a better solution that removes any need to track the keyboard state in the sub-view.

My parent view no longer uses a `UIGestureRecognizer`, but instead uses a custom subclass of `UIView` to track touch events, and conditionally ignore them:

```
class KeyboardDismissingView: UIView {

    private var keyboardVisible = false

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard let r = super.hitTest(point, with: event) else { return nil }
        var v : UIView! = r
        while v != nil {
            if v is UITextField {
                return r
            }
            v = v.superview
        }

        if keyboardVisible {
            self.endEditing(false)
            return nil
        }

        return r
    }

    func setup() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardShown), name:
            NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UIKeyboardDidShowNotification"), object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardHidden), name:
            NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UIKeyboardDidHideNotification"), object: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func keyboardShown(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        keyboardVisible = true
    }

    @IBAction func keyboardHidden(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        keyboardVisible = false
    }

    override init (frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        setup()
    }
}
```